# Stable URL of acts_as_taggable plugin in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable

In one of my applications on Ruby on Rails, I am using acts_as_taggable plugin. Coding was doing fine and suddenly it started giving following error.

RuntimeError (acts_as_taggable_on_steroids has been moved to github: http://github.com/jviney/acts_as_taggable_on_steroids):
  app/models/post.rb:2
  app/controllers/post_controller.rb:324:in `post_scoper'
  app/controllers/post_controller.rb:221:in`default'
  C:\MyApp\script\server:3
  -e:2:in `load'
  -e:2

Rendered rescues/_trace (94.0ms)
Rendered rescues/_request_and_response (15.0ms)
Rendering rescues/layout (internal_server_error)

When trying installing the plugin from above URL, it says plugin has been moved.

Does anyone have idea, what is the stable URL of acts_as_taggable plugin?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can still get it at http://github.com/jviney/acts_as_taggable_on_steroids

```
ruby script/plugin install git://github.com/jviney/acts_as_taggable_on_steroids.git
```